# Need help using a Service Reference in VS 2010

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, soap

This is my first time consuming a SOAP web service in ASP.Net and I am a little lost on how this works.

https://www.secureach.com/AchProcessorWebService/AchProcessorService.asmx

I created the Service Reference called AchProcessor in VS 2010 and now I have some Code hints in the VS editor. My first bit of code looks like this..

```
AchProcessor.WebServiceInfoRequest ws = new AchProcessor.WebServiceInfoRequest();
```

At this point I am kind of lost.. if I type ws. the only code hint I get is 'Body' with the exception of ToString, GetType etc...

Comment: Look in the Object Browser. You'll see all the other types, including `AchProcessor`, which is the service as a whole.

Comment: Thanks John, I see all the types in there that match up with the different service methods but still lost on how it actually sends the request and handles the response. Unfortunately the service provider has zero support resources for developers that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio would have generated the code using `svcutil` (or an app named along these lines) as you have seen, among such code is a proxy, or, a `client`, and this can be used as follows:

```
using (var client = new MyWebServiceClient())
{
    var result = client.MyMethod();   
}
```

So, in your case, `MyWebServiceClient` should be replaced with `AchProcessorClient`. As mentioned above by John Saunders, use the Object Browser to determine the definite name of the type if not so easily found as described here.

Although an appropriate binding for the service is most likely already in the configuration file, it is worth mentioning that you can actually specify the binding used in the constructor of the client, too.